# Why do child classes in python not share the same pointers to a parent class function?

Tags: python, inheritance, parent-child

I was trying to test whether a class had a certain function as a variable, and to test was doing so by comparing it to the parents function that the child class was initialised with, but found that they existed at differing memory addresses. The following code exhibits this behaviour:

```
>>> class common():
        def a():
            print('hello')

>>> class one(common):
        def __init__(self):
            self.fn = super().a

>>> var1 = one()
>>> var2 = one()
>>> var1.fn == var2.fn
False
>>> var1.fn is var2.fn
False
>>> var1.fn
<bound method common.a of <__main__.one object at 0x0737CC50>>
>>> var2.fn
<bound method common.a of <__main__.one object at 0x0737CAF0>>
```

Why is this? And is there any way around it so I can check if they are equivalent?

Edit:

And why should the above be any different to below?:

```
>>> def h(x):
    return x+2

>>> var1 = h
>>> var2 = h
>>> var1 == var2
True
>>> var1 is var2
True
>>> var1
<function h at 0x073824F8>
>>> var2
<function h at 0x073824F8>
```

Comment: Those are different objects' methods. Even if it weren't for other complications (like the descriptor protocol), why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Because they are both referencing the same parent class, and even if they weren't, why should they point to different functions? This is a reasonable assumption because outside of classes, when you create a function in python it is created once at one memory location, and no matter how many times you reference it it will only ever be at the one memory location

Comment: You're not accessing the function. You're accessing instance methods. `super().whatever` doesn't mean `SuperclassNameHere.whatever`.